# Electric field near an a conductor which is near an insulating sheet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, charge

A thin sheet of magnitude A has uniform charge Q> 0, and is closely placed near a conductor of width d. The conductor has net charge of zero. In terms of the given quantities and fundamental constants, find the charge density on both the near and far surfaces of the conductor, and the electric field strength in each of the four regions. Indicate the direction of the electric field in each region using vectors
[image]

Frankly, I am quite unsure of where to even begin for this problem, I am not asking anyone to do my work for me but it would extremely helpful if anyone could explain the underlining physics of how a conductor and charged insulator sheet interact. I presume that the sheet would induce some negative charge on the side of the conductor closest to the sheet which would also mean that there would be a positive charge to the other side of the conductor. However, I do not no what the magnitude of these charges would be. After that the electric field calculation should be easy to find for each part. I believe I would then use super position to find the field in each region, but if I am wrong on that tell me.

Comment: what does it mean for a sheet to have a magnitude A?  Do you mean it is of area A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I presume that the sheet would induce some negative charge on the side of the conductor closest to the sheet which would also mean that there would be a positive charge to the other side of the conductor. However, I do not no what the magnitude of these charges would be.

As a hint, what do you know about the electric field inside a good conductor in steady state conditions?

What would the charge on each surface of the conductor need to be to establish this condition?

If it helps, think about how you use Gauss's law to find the field due to a sheet of charge, and how you can apply a similar Gaussian surface in this problem.